# How to create code behind class file in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to create index.aspx.cs file in mvc like you do in asp.net.

Can anybody tell me the process for this?

Answer (score 5):

You do not create code behind classes for asp.net mvc views. Use [controllers](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials#Controllers) instead.